# xsl value as an ID of element

Tags: java, html, xslt

I am trying to create a HTML file from an XML using xslt. 
I am trying to use a value exported from xml as an ID for one of the elements of the page. but xls fails to compile.

My code is

```
       <td data-open="<xsl:value-of select="@name" />">Fail<xsl:value-of select="failure/@message" /></td>
```

How can I use the returned value in my template ? is there an escape character for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute an attribute value of a literal result element with an XPath expression, you can use an attribute value template `<td data-open="{@name}">...</td>`.